# Switch between native and custom select with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html-select

I have a jQuery mobile SELECT, which options are changed dynamically, I need to change from a native select to a custom select to show the options (data-native-menu) depending on the number of options (and without changing the page).

Example: If I push a button I changed the number of options in the select to be five dynamically and I would like to show the select as native, then, if I push another button, I changed the options to be 2, so i would want to show it as custom.

Any ideas? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to just have two select boxes?  One that has the styling applied and one that does not?  Then depending on the size of the collection you are using you just show the correct select box?

I tried creating an example of dynamically applying/removing jquery mobile styling to 1 select box and I am just not sure its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the JQM custom select does involve pretty sustantial DOM modifications (think of the subPage with a list of all your options linked to your original select), I don't know if you can just switch between both modes easily.

You can always rebuild the select after modifying number of options like so:

```
//refresh value         
$('select').selectmenu('refresh');

//refresh and force rebuild
$('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Taken from [JQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/selects/methods.html). Just try to add/remove the data-native-attribute here and see what happens.

I'm usually setting selects on page load like so:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page").basePage').on('pagebeforecreate', function() {  

    // Jquery Mobile Custom Select
if ( !$.support.touch ) {       
    $(this).find('select').attr('data-native-menu',false);
    }
});
```

This way on touch devices all selects will get the *data-native-menu* attribute and will be "enhanced" to native selects, while on desktop JQM takes over and creates custom selects.

I think this is the "best-looking" way of doing things. Just make sure to add the attrbutes *before* JQM enhances elements.

Comment: Im using an iPod, refreshing the options is not the problem, I set data-native-menu=false so It will be show as native, but the problem is changing from native to custom when the number of options changes in the same select, doing something like $(select).attr('data-native-menu',true) dont do the trick, I have tried to change the DOM dynamically as JQM does, but it doesnt work neither, i guess because of JQM events missing, any more ideas ¿

Comment: have you tried refreshing the select after modifying options. Check the link in the answer - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/selects/methods.html = call $('select').selectmenu('refresh');

Comment: yep, first thing i tried, unfortunately for me it didnt work. Forgot to mentioned im using JQM 1.0

Comment: Ok. Please try calling selectmenu('refresh') on the wrapping div = should be div.ui-select.

Comment: Looks like its not easy as that, I'll have to re-render my self the div "select-menu" which should be refreshed by the JQM